# Is there a way to execute some code on a google chrome loaded webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a webpage that requires all zero values to replaced with an alphabet 'A' in about 600 to 700 records.

I can do it manually one by one, but that usually takes me an hour or so.
I was wondering if there is a way to execute some sort of javascript or any code/script to automate my process, since there is a console window in google chrome and the whole webpage with records is loaded into cache. I myself am an intermediate web developer, but i only use the console window for indentifying bugs.

Is there a way?

It will be life-saving if someone provides the solution to my process.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: yes you can execute js codes from the console and do any modification to the dom but keep in mind it doesn't change the actual web page.alternatively you can use grease monkey / temper monkey to use modification code  as a extension

Comment: can you give an example of the code that you are talking about and explain why zero values must be replaced with `A`

Comment: basically, there is an examination form, where the default value is zero with every candidate and about 400 out of 600 are Absent and the zeros need to be changed with 'A'. They're all textboxes